# (MySql) select query returns empty row in WHERE and AND condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two related table,a one to many relations.I can display values on a selected column in where condition

[image]

What is the correct way when adding 'AND' clause in the above query?I tried this queries but it result empty set.

[image]

Comment: date_created is probably a date and not a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values in `date_created` all include a time component `08:00:00`. However, you are comparing it as equal to the date value `'2014-03-13'` which implies `2014-03-12 00:00:00`, and is therefore *not* equal to `2014-03-12 08:00:00`

To make that comparison the way you are attempting, you need to truncate the value in `date_created` to only the date portion, removing the time with MySQL's [native `DATE()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date).

```
SELECT date_created 
FROM collections
WHERE 
  -- Truncate the datetime to a date only
  DATE(date_created) = '2014-03-12'
  AND loan_id = 3942
```

The above example is that of your first query attempt, but using the `JOIN` requires the same solution in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. I change my query into

```
SELECT 
      date_created 
FROM collections 
WHERE DATE(date_created) = '2014-03-12' AND loan_id = 3942;
```

Now it returns rows with the specific dates.